# How can i merge Rows of An HTML table fetched from Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a MySQL database for a website am building, i have displayed contents of a table in the MySQL database on my page using the PHP code shown below. What i wanted to know was if there was a way to Merge rows of a column with the same value.

note: i don't want the changes to occur in the database but just on the html table displayed on the page
here is the code i used

```
$arr = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    if (empty($arr[$row[0]])) $arr[$row[0]] = array();
    $arr[$row[0]] [$row[1]] [$row[2]] [$row[3]] [$row[4]] [$row[5]] [$row[6]][] = $row[7];

}
foreach ($arr as $key => $subordinatearr) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td rowspan="', count($subordinatearr), '">', $key, '</td>';
    echo '<td>', $subordinatearr[0], '</td>';
    echo '<td>', $subordinatearr[1], '</td>';
    echo '<td>', $subordinatearr[2], '</td>';
    echo '<td>', $subordinatearr[3], '</td>';
    echo '<td>', $subordinatearr[4], '</td>';
    echo '<td>', $subordinatearr[5], '</td>';
    echo '<td>', $subordinatearr[6], '</td>';

    if (count($subordinatearr) > 1) {
        for ($i = 1; $i < count($subordinatearr); $i++) {
            echo '</tr><tr><td>', $subordinatearr[$i], '</td>';
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using 'colspan' for that? What I understood from your question is that you check if the values of row[0] and row[1] are same then merge the two table cells using colspan

Comment: Use PDO or Mysqli instead of Mysql... But, other than that, if you are trying to combine two tables you probably need a UNION or JOIN statement in your SQL query.  But we need more information about the structure of your tables to help more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the result in an array.

```
$arr = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    if (empty($arr[$row[0]]) $arr[$row[0]] = array();
    $arr[$row[0]][] = $row[1]; 
}
```

Then put the array using rowspan like as follows:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $subordinatearr) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td rowspan="', count($subordinatearr), '">', $key, '</td>';
    echo '<td>', $subordinatearr[0], '</td>';
    if (count($subordinatearr) > 1) {
        for ($i = 1; $i < count($subordinatearr); $i++) {
            echo '</tr><tr><td>', $subordinatearr[$i], '</td>';
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

If data is too big, this may cause an memory error.

Comment: this sounds & seems like what am looking for but for some reason it's not displaying anything

Comment: any idea why that is buddy

Comment: I'm very sorry. for loop was wrong. It should be as follows:        for ($i = 1; $i < count($subordinatearr); $i++) {

Comment: I corrected the error in the original answer. Please check.

Comment: :D it did display the data but not in a table format, anyway i can manage that?

Comment: What do i change when the column number increases, lets say there were 6 other columns

Comment: You can increase the nesting level of arrays. Like `$arr[$item1][$item2][$item3][$item4][$item5][] = $item6;` But this strategy only works when the data is in a tree structure. If a cell in the second column should relate to two cells in the first column, the program gets far more complex.

Comment: it's not working, i edit the code on the original question could you pls have a look? am sure by now you know am a novice at PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Please change this script to

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";           
    echo "<td>".$row['Location']."</td>";  
    echo "<td>".$row['Vessel ']."</td>"; 
    echo "</tr>";
 }
```

Comment: it works fine as it is. what i wanted was a way to merge rows if they have the same data. for e.g. if the table have 4 rows 
`Locatio Vessel</br>
xx       12</br>
xx       1</br>
xx       13</br>
yy       15</br>`

i wanted it to be displayed like this
`Locatio Vessel</br>
         12</br>
xx       1</br>
         13</br>
yy       15</br>`

Comment: while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";           
    echo "<td>".$row['Location']."&nbsp;".$row['Vessel ']."</td>";     
    echo "</tr>";
 }

Comment: and also do this   <th>Location Vessel </th>

Comment: it works in the first place....what i want is a way to merge rows if they have the same data. something like what @k.abbey suggested. have a look at his comment

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand this part clearly - "Merge rows of a column with the same value."
If you don't want to show duplicate records of a column, you can do it in two ways -

### Option 1

Keep the value of specific column in an array. Before displaying that column check if the value exists in the array using is_array(). If exists, then skip, otherwise show and add into the array.

### Option 2

While making the query, use DISTINCT(col_name) to get only the unique values.

Comment: what i meant was how can i merge rows with the same data for e.g. if i have 3 rows in my table & the Location field in all 3 rows have the same data i want to do something like a rawspan on those 3 rows with the same data. got it? but i don't know how i can do that